# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean : org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware

Tags: java, spring, noclassdeffounderror

I am new to this forum. I am trying to make an application using spring 3.2.6 and tomcat 7.0. I have added all the necessary jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder. The DispatcherServlet and ContextLoaderListener is properly configured in the web.xml. The same application was working fine with spring 3.0.2 version. Now when I am trying to open the jsp page, it is giving me below error:

> HTTP Status 500 - org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean :
>   org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware
>
> ---
>
> type Exception report
>
> message org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean :
>   org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean :
>   org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
>     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
>     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
>     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.

The jar

> spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE

is already added in the classpath. I am able to open the class file also from the Eclipse. But I don't understand why it is giving class not found error at run time. I tried to search it on google but didn't find exact the solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works for an older version(as you say), What I guess there are some places you have old jar in the path, which mess up the jar dependency 
I will suggest you do a full disk search to find out all your spring jar location and clean them up.
BTW: you can try to add jar to tomcat/lib to try also (it is not proper practice, but this can help to find out whether it is path related issue).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. There were spring jars in the plugins folder of the eclipse installation. I tried removing those but didn't work. Then as per your suggestion, just copied the jar in the tomcat/lib folder and the error was not coming. But in this way I had to add all the jar which was not proper solution. Finally I just created new workspace and configure the project again which solved the issue. But I am still not sure about the error cause. Anyway, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean` is part of `spring-webmvc`. You will need to add that library to your classpath as well. You can get it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I have already added spring-webmvc-3.2.6.RELEASE in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: @DDP Right click your project, select `Properties` and go to `Deployment Assembly` and `Build Path`. Are you jars added?

Comment: Yes. jars are added there. Even I tried by adding both the jars as external jars using Java >Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs But still it gives the same error.

Comment: @DDP Can you add an image (or just write it up) of your directory structure?

Comment: I am unable to upload the image so I giving you the hierarchy in brief. It has WebContent -> WEB-INF ->lib. There are several other packages under src folder for model and controllers. But all the jars are placed in the lib folder

Comment: @DDP Try deleting your Tomcat server instance and creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

EnvironmentAware is located in the spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, so you are missing that one.

Also recheck your Maven POM file so that you are not missing any other Spring library, like spring-web, spring-webmvc (you may have these since the DispatcherServlet class if found), spring-orm if you use an ORM like Hibernate, spring-jms if you use JMS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I solved it by adding the jar:

org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar

to both the build path and as a maven dependency ([java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765821/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv))

Hope it helps